# Why does the exponential map have this form?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I *believe* I understand what the exponential map does, in informal terms. However I cannot relate this to the equation I see before me in the papers.

The exponential mapping function for a symmetric matrix $A$ belonging to the tangent space at $X$, $T_x\mathcal{P}_n$ is:
$S_A = Exp(A) = X^\frac{1}{2} exp(X^{-\frac{1}{2}} A X^{-\frac{1}{2}}) X^\frac{1}{2} $

where $Exp()$ is the exponential map and $exp()$ is the matrix exponential.

My informal understanding is that the exponential map takes a tangent vector and travels along the geodesic whose tangent is that vector. The point that you end up at $S_A$ is the same distance from along the geodesic from X as the length of the tangent vector.

Presuming that my *intuition* is correct - how do I relate this to the equation? Why is this $X^\frac{1}{2}$  decomposition going on..? What purpose does the exponential of the matrix serve?